# Angular UI router when abstract state parent route, child state controller not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am using UI router and my 2 states use the same view. My approach is as follows.

```
<button ui-sref="test.state1">

.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('test.state1', {
      url: '/mystate/start',
      template: require('./myPage.html'),
      controller: function ($scope, myService) {
        console.log('2 ctrl called ');
        myService.myMethod().then(function () {
          console.log('3 calling my method ');
        });
      },
      resolve: {
        testOne: [function () {
             //service call 
        }],
        testTwo: [function () {
             //service call
        }] 
      }
    }).state('test.state2', {
    url: '/mystate/end',
    template: require('./myPage.html'),
    controller: 'MyController as myctr'
  });
}])
```

I can see my console logs in order of 1,2 and 3, first resolving the data and then hitting inline controller.

I am trying to change this to use abstract parameter.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('test', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/mystate',
        template: require('./myPage.html')
    })
    .state('test.state1', {
        url: '/start',
        controller: function ($scope, myService) {
          console.log('2 ctrl called ');
          myService.myMethod().then(function () {
            console.log('3 calling my method ');
          });
        },
        resolve: {
          testOne: [function () {
             //service call 
        }],
        testTwo: [function () {
             //service call
        }] 
        }
    })
    .state('test.state2', {
        url: '/end',
        controller: 'MyController as myctr'
    })
```

Now I can only see the resolve and the inline ctrl doesn't get invoked. Is it something that I am missing in the setup ? documentation [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) is inconclusive.

Comment: those `resolve`'s are invalid javascript. You can't invoke a function directly between `{}`

Comment: code updated to have correct resolve code

Comment: Suggest you create simple demo that replicates problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rpwfnmih05EzPqfy3atY?p=preview

state - test.state1 shows one and two but should show '2 ctrl called ' as well, since after resolve, the controller block should get executed, but doesn't happen that way..confused

Comment: Demo doesn't work because there is no `<ui-view>` inside `one.html`. Also using old version of angular with most current ui-router. Make sure they are compatible